# How can I redirect user back to my SSO service with Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on

my application is designed to use an SSO service for authentication. The scenario is similar to the Siteminder scenario on Spring's documentation. A user comes from the SSO already authenticated.

However, if the user visits the application and is not authenticated yet, I'd like to redirect the user to the SSO login form.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please provide more details : an SSO server name and SSO plugin from Spring Security side (if any)

Comment: this is a proprietary service with no Spring plugin. I've posted a solution I found, though it comes off as a bit strange for me.

Comment: I think to prove you solution you can look into spring-security-cas sources. Try to find a handler for this particular situation and compare it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Http403Redirect extends Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Http403Redirect.class)

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, AuthenticationException arg2) 
        throws IOException ,ServletException {
        arg1.setStatus(403)
        arg1.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com/")
    }
}
```

And in my servlet security xml configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="com.opentext.infofusion.security.otds.Http403Redirect" />

<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('user')" />
    <custom-filter ref="otdsFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
</http>
```

This seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using the custom-filter is the way I have accomplished this in the past as well.  One thing to add is that the form-login can redirect already to you sso page if the user is not authenticated.

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
    <form-login login-page="${ssoPage}" authentication-failure-url="${ssoPage}"/>
    <custom-filter ref="jeePreAuthenticatedFilter"  position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout.jsp" delete-cookies="MYSubject"/>
</http>

<!-- J2EE pre-authentication -->
<beans:bean id="jeePreAuthenticatedFilter" class="com.example.MyCustomFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"  ref="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" class="com.example.MyCustomUserDetailsService">

</beans:bean>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Whats in your MyCustomFilter ? How do you get redirected back to your pre auth filter from the external sso login page ?